# What is a Bm chord with a G in it?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I am writing a song with `G > Bm > Em` as the main chord progression but I found a lot of nice fingerings on the guitar for the Bm chord with an added G in it. Does this make the chord a B minor 6 chord? Or does it change the chord into something else?

Comment: Bm6 has G#, not G.

Comment: If the G is at the bottom, it’s a G7. If the G is elsewhere it’s a Bm-6 (B minor flat six, or B minor with a flattened sixth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be

`G - B - D - F#` ( G + Bm) which is the **Gmaj7** chord // G can be something else besides the bass note, and then it would be a Gmaj7 chord in some inversion. With B as the bass note it would be Gmaj7 in first inversion.

Something else that is really common in harmony, that can easily be done in your chord progression is to play the G chord, then the Bm chord with the G held from the previous chord as suspension that will be later be resolved to a chord note (F# for instance).

Also, since the note G is present both in the first and last chords of your progression (G and Em respectively), it's not uncommon to hold it for the middle chord as well.

Comment: I agree with the Gmaj7 analysis, but doesn't Bm6 have a G# in it? Not a G natural.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS tbh I'm not 100% sure, but usually I've seen it with a minor 6th, thus G natural. On guitar that is

Comment: I doubt you've usually seen Bm6 with a G natural! It's 99% of the time G#! It's the B that's minor, not Bm with a m6 interval included! At a (huge) push, it *could* be Bm (addm6), but pretty unusual.

Comment: Must've misremembered. Fixed it

Comment: @Tim I don't understand why it has to be a minor chord with a major 6th interval. Can't it be a minor chord with a minor 6th interval or does that change the chord to an inversion of another chord as explained above?

Comment: @armani - if you play those four notes - B D F# and G in close voicing as a root position chord, you'll hear that it doesn't work too well. Minor 6 chords have always been (and always will be!) a minor thriad with the addition of a major 6 note.

Comment: @Tim I am playing it on the guitar and it sounds like it does work to my ears. Specifically I am playing 
B (second fret on A string)
G (open G string)
D (third fret on B string)
F# (second fret on high E string) 
Can't understand why you say this doesnt work

Comment: @armani - you're really playing Gmaj7, 1st inversion. Those four notes make that chord. There is no Bm triad with a m6 as well. It's like saying CEG (Cmaj) is actually Em addm6, or it's really G6sus4(no5). There's little to no point!

Comment: @armani I must respectfully disagree a little with `@Tim. Certainly sometimes it would make sense to analyse those notes as a B chord. The X-files theme has its distinctive sound from the notes A-C-E-F, which of course spells an F major triad. However, the theme is clearly in A minor, and it makes way more sense to analyse the chord as an A minor chord. If hard pressed for a name, I'd go for Am♭6.

Comment: @Tim See my above comment about the X-files theme. A-C-E-F makes an Am chord in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how this is voiced, this F♯ might be better understood not as a chord tone but as a passing tone from the G in the first chord to the E in the last chord.

For example:

[image]

Some musicians have a habit of making a chord out of every vertical stacking of pitches. But sometimes (perhaps most of the time?) there's a melodic explanation that is much more intuitive and that aligns with the flow of the music much better.

Comment: Agree with your last para., but what chord symbol would go for that second bar - for a guitarist, maybe? it's going to be Gmaj7...

Comment: Do I have to agree with how guitar music is typically explained/notated? :-)

Comment: Come on! Without a letter and sometimes a number, a lot of guitarists go very quiet..!

Answer (score 2):

Since the first chord is already a G, I think I would probably just call it Gmaj7 which is G B D F#.

If the added G is in the bass, you could also just call it a Bm chord over a G in the bass, which would be notated like this: Bm/G

A Bm6 chord would be B - D - F# - G# instead of G natural.

Comment: The G is not in the bass. There is a B in the bass

Comment: @armani Then it's Gmaj7 in 1st inversion.